# how to add to rspec-rails callbacks

Tags: rspec

I have some code that adds to the callbacks that rspec-rails adds by default to [setup and teardown fixtures](http://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/spec/rails/interop/testcase.rb).

My code looks something like:

```
module Test
  module Unit

    class TestCase
      append_before(:each) do
       Test::Unit::AfterFixturesLoaded.custom_stuff1
      end

      append_after(:each) do
        Test::Unit::AfterFixturesLoaded.custom_stuff2
      end
    end

    class AfterFixturesLoaded

      def self.custom_stuff1
        #do some stuff here
      end

      def self.custom_stuff2
        #do some other stuff here
      end
    end

  end
end
```

This code works fine if I put it in the config\initializers directory in the rails app, but then running the app fails because it doesn't load test unit. So my question is where can I put this code so that it will always be included when running rspec?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only going to use this code for testing so it make sense to put it in a separate file and then require it in the `environments/test.rb` for example `require 'filename.rb'`